# P, Q, R, S and T are on line k such that Q is the midpoint of PT, R is the midpoint of QT, and S is the midpoint of RT. If PS=9, what is PT equal to?

Tags: geometry

I said PT = 12 but I still don't quite understand how I did it. I literally just guessed that it was gonna be 12 because of the proportions. Could someone explain why it is 12? I said PQ is 6, therefore QT is 6, and half of that is 3, and half of that is 1,5 but I still don't understand.

Comment: Have you tried making a sketch of the situation?

Comment: Answer 12 is wrong. Let $ST=a$, then $RS= ...$, then $RT=...$, then $QR=...$, then $QT=...$, then $PQ=...$, then $PT=...$. After filling the gaps use the information given in problem statement and find $a$, then use it to find required information.